# Can't connect PHP to MongoDB in Google Cloud

Tags: php, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect my PHP app to MongoDB in Google Cloud but I'm getting an error. Those are the steps I followed.

1- MongoDB is installed and working with Bitnami's launcher

2- I installed mongodb PHP extension

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

[image]

3- I created a php.ini file in the root (same directory as app.yaml) and added the extension

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

**Error**

Neither `phpinfo` or `extension_loaded` shows mongodb extension as loaded in my server, therefore, I can't connect. Can anyone help me to figure out what am I missing?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mongodb` installs mongodb server, not *mongodb PHP extension*. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php

Comment: Thanks Alex!! I understand I need to execute 'sudo pecl install mongodb' instead, but the result appears to be the same. That command is not working properly on my Cloud (ERROR: `make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root2GYEZ5/install-mongodb-1.4.2" install' failed), nonetheless, I'm going to  check

Comment: You need to check why the installation failed. Most likely some dependencies are missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex,  'sudo apt-get install php-mongodb' did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution. The problem, as Alex suggested in his comment, was that I was installing the server and not the PHP driver.

That made the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to add mongodb extension is as follows(see [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#PHP_Enabled_extensions)):

```
extension = "mongo.so"
```

Also as Alex Blex commented, `sudo apt-get install mongodb` installs the mongodb itself. My understanding is that you don't need to install neither that nor the extension, Google App Engine Flex environment already supports this via `php.ini` configuration.